# How to cut a list by max sum

Tags: list-manipulation

```
{5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7}
```

let `maxsum=20`, then I get `{{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}` , all the sum of sublist $\le$ maxsum. (Assume there won't be any element $>$ maxsum)

This is what I have coded.

```
F[x_] := Module[{a = {}, s = {}}, Do[AppendTo[s, i]; If[Total[s] > 20, AppendTo[a, s // Most];
s = {i}], {i, x}]; AppendTo[a, s]; a]

F[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4}, {3}}*)
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Similar to [268488](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268488/partitioning-a-list-based-on-a-criterion-for-sublists) that was asked in 2022.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Split

```
ClearAll[split]
split[lst_, maxsum_] := Module[{s = lst[[1]]},
  Split[lst, Or[(s+= #2) <= maxsum, s = #2] &]]
```

***Examples:***

```
split[{5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}
> ```

```
split[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4}, {3}}
> ```

#### SequenceSplit

```
ClearAll[seqSplit]
seqSplit = SequenceSplit[#, a : {__} /; Total[a] <= #2 :> a] &;

seqSplit[{5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7}, 20]
```

> ```
> {{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}
> ```

```
seqSplit[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4}, {3}}
> ```

#### Reap + Sow

```
ClearAll[reapSow]
reapSow[lst_, maxsum_] := Module[{i = 0, s = 0}, 
  Last @ Reap[Scan[Sow[#, If[(s += #) <= maxsum, i, s = #; ++i]] &, lst]]]

reapSow[{5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7}, 20]
```

> ```
> {{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}
> ```

```
reapSow[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4}, {3}}
> ```

#### ReplaceRepeated + TakeDrop + Accumulate

```
takeDrop[lst_, maxsum_] := {lst} //. {a___List, b_List} /; Length[b] > 1 :> 
      {a, ## & @@ TakeDrop[b, LengthWhile[Accumulate[b], # <= maxsum &]]} //
   DeleteCases[{}]

takeDrop[{5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}
> ```

```
takeDrop[{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3}, 20]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4}, {3}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
$$List = {5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7};

$$Sum = 0; $Max$Value = 20;
 {#, Length@#}& @
     TakeWhile[$$List, (($$Sum += #) <= $Max$Value) &]

(*{{5, 10, 3}, 3}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7};
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[list, a_ /; Total[a] <= 20]
```

{{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {5, 10, 3, 8, 9, 8, 8, 4, 1, 7};
```

Using `SequenceReplace`:

```
SequenceReplace[list, {a__} /; Total[{a}] <= 20 :> {a}]

(*{{5, 10, 3}, {8, 9}, {8, 8, 4}, {1, 7}}*)
```